# PySide - Get list of all visible rows in a table

Tags: python, qt, pyside

Given that I have an instance of QTableView (or a subclass thereof), connected to a subclass of QAbstractTableModel (or functionally equivalent model + view), is it possible to get a list of the indexes of all rows currently *visible* to the user (i.e. those not falling outside the current scroll range)?

It would be great if the solution scales to different window/screen sizes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain the item position using `QAbstractItemView::visualRect`. It is in the viewport coordinates, so we need to check if it is in the viewport rect. Here is an example:

```
viewport_rect = QRect(QPoint(0, 0), self.view.viewport().size())
for row in range(0, self.model.rowCount()):
  rect = self.view.visualRect(self.model.index(row, 0))
  is_visible = viewport_rect.intersects(rect)
```

This example works only with one column, but you can add a `for` loop for iterate over all columns.

In this code items are considered visible if they are partially visible. If you want to get only items that are completely visible, use `contains` instead of `intersects`.

Comment: Excellent. In its current for it is perhaps a bit computationally heavy for constant use (we need to dynamically load additional row data into memory whenever the user brings new rows into view), but this is absolutely a foundation to work on. Thank you very much!